# Multiple check on a string and count

Tags: mysql, string, count

I have a string with numbers and letters, and i made a function that check the string, but i need to add a count.
This is the example string :
2B-5D-3F-12C-8B-9H, 
1A-1B-4D-5D-2A-6O,

I want to check in each string how much time they have same letters or numbers.
In the first sequence i've 2 same letters (2B 8B), in second string i've 2 same numbers ( 1A 1B ) and 2 same Letters ( 1A-2A and 4D-5D ).
How i can have an output of all matched letters and numbers , without made a substr_count for each numbers or letters ?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS product. by using substr_count it seems you are using oracle.

Comment: no i use Mysql Db